# On Pixel7, a NativeNfcTag error occurs about once in five times

Tags: android, nfc, pixel

On Pixel 7, a NativeNfcTag error occurs about once in five times.

When an error occurred, the following log was output.

```
3833-6542  libnfc_nci   pid-3833   E  [ERROR:NativeNfcTag.cpp(946)] nativeNfcTag_doTransceive: wait response timeout
3833-6542  libnfc_nci   pid-3833   E  [ERROR:NfcTag.cpp(1533)] NfcTag::getTransceiveTimeout: invalid tech=-1
3833-6542  libnfc_nci   pid-3833   E  [ERROR:NfcTag.cpp(1533)] NfcTag::getTransceiveTimeout: invalid tech=-1
3833-4256  libnfc_nci   pid-3833   E  [ERROR:NfcTag.cpp(1533)] NfcTag::getTransceiveTimeout: invalid tech=-1
```

I tried it on pixel4a and pixel6, but it did not occur.
Please tell me the cause and solution.

Comment: What are you doing that it happens to you and never to me?

Comment: Showing your code on what you are Transceive'ing to the tag might help, as well as the make and model of the Tag, otherwise we are guessing on what the problem might be. Also have you changed the default timeout on NFC comms?

Comment: Thank you for the advice.
The code that actually performs NFC processing is an external library, so I don't know how to use the native code.
From the logs, we can see that sometimes the NFC tag type is invalid, so it seems that the appropriate timeout value cannot be set and it is failing.
It is very strange that only Pixel 7 is occasionally affected.